# Cannot figure out how to fix this css

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-animations

I am new to the **Angular** 8 framework. I am trying to implement animation using angular animations

Here is what the code looks like:

This component is in `<div class="col-md-5"></div>` as a parent div.

**component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-agent-bot',
  templateUrl: './agent-bot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agent-bot.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('bot_res_slide', [
      transition('* => *', [
        animate('2s', keyframes([
          style({ transform: 'translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)', visibility: 'visible' }),
          style({ transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)' })
        ]))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

**component.html**

```
<main>
  <div class="bot shadow-sm" [ngStyle]="{height: botHeight}">
    <div class="bot_header p-2 rounded-top">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="color_blue">
            <i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="ml-3">AGENT BOT</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bot_body rounded-bottom d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="p-2">

        <div class="bot_response" @bot_res_slide>
          <div class="bot_response_msg">
            Hello Agent! How may I help?
          </div>
          <div class="bot_response_msg_time">03:00pm</div>
        </div>

        <div class="user_response">
          <div class="user_response_msg">
            Hi..!
          </div>
          <div class="user_response_msg_time">03:01pm</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="mt-auto d-flex border-top input_section">
        <div class="canned_msg">
          <img src="./../../../assets/icons/canned_icon.png" class="w-100 h-100">
        </div>
        <div class="h-100 w-100 border-left">
          <input type="text" class="user_input" placeholder="Type here" />
        </div>
        <div class="send_msg_btn d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center px-3">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane my-auto" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**Here is what the output looks like:**
[image: Here is what the output looks like]

The expected output is the animation should only work in the bot component and should not be displayed outside.

Where am I going wrong or where should I improve my code?

Comment: What exactly are you asking, it isn't very clear?

Comment: If we take a look at the image presented in the question, we can see the chat message comes flying from left from outside the div. It should not be visible outside the chatbot. If I am still not clear, please let me know

Comment: I submitted my best answer on how to best fix your issue with some css and what I am assuming is AngluarJS.

Comment: Thankyou verymuch. `overflow: hidden` did solve the problem

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe that your issue is in the way you've done a simple `translateX` job with the `translate3d` property. Your element is showing up from the far left because the syntax of `transform3d(x, y, z)` values and you've made it travel the whole page (100%). For a slide, I'd recommend changing to a `transform: translateX(value)` to use the best function for the job. As well as define the `transform-origin` to be aligned to the edge of your message/ bot container. @vishalbiswas also has a possible solution by using `overflow: hidden` on the containing element.

```
...
style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)', visibility: 'visible' }),
style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })
...
```

In CSS:

```
.bot-response {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the message list container (`.bot_body`).
This will clip the child elements rendering outside the container